# Convert List To List of Tuples C#

Tags: c#, list, tuples

How can i convert a List of Items to a List of Tuples.

Example 1:
Sourcelist [item1]
Destinationlist [{item1, null}]

Example 2:
Sourcelist [item1, item2]
Destinationlist [{item1, item2}]

Example 2:
Sourcelist [item1, item2, item3]
Destinationlist [{item1, item2}, {item3, null]]

Comment: Can you show us what have you already tried?

Comment: using LINQ's `Select`

Comment: I'm confused - do you have a list of _arrays_?  If not, what is `Sourcelist [item1, item2]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First use the overload of `Select` that includes the index.  Then group on the index divided by 2.  Finally put the grouping, which will have one or two items into the `Tuple`.

```
var result = source.Select((v,i) => new { Index = i, Value = v })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Index/2, x => x.Value)
    .Select(g => Tuple.Create(g.First(), g.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()));
```

Comment: Perfektly, Thanks